# input to stringstream and convert to string in single statement. Possible without helper class?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I would like to write code like this:

```
std::string s = ??? << "asdf" << 123;
```

I am not sure what to place for the `???` to make it work. I can write a helper class:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Stringify {
  std::stringstream o;
  template <typename T> 
  Stringify& operator<<(const T& t){
    o << t;
    return *this;
  }
  operator std::string(){ return o.str(); }
};

int main(){
  std::string s;
  s = Stringify() << " test " << 123 << " asd";
  std::cout << s << std::endl;   
}
```

...but I am not able to do it wihtout the helper class. I tried different things, the nicest error message i got from this:

```
  s =  (std::stringstream() << "test" << 123 << " asd").str();

  -> error: ‘class std::basic_ostream<char>’ has no member named ‘str’
```

I also tried more, but it just resulted in more complicated error messages.

Is it possible to do what I want without having to write a helper class? If not, is there any good reason why it isnt possible only with `std` stuff?

Comment: What's wrong with the helper class?

Comment: The error is due to `operator<<` returning an `std::ostream &` (bound to the string stream).

Comment: @DanielJour there is nothing wrong with it, but I dont want to use it if it can be done without it. Also I would be surprised if it wasnt possible without it, as it merely forwards the `<<` and provides acces to `.str()` but it does not really add anything other than making `<<` return the same type again.... maybe thats the point that cannot be done without it, but I am not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
std::string s = static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << 7 << 10 << 12).str();
```

Comment: [seems to work](http://ideone.com/FrRy3W), but for some reason I get rubbish printed on my local machine when the first thing I put into the stream is a string. E.g. `<< "asd"` and then `cout` will print `0x400e60`

Comment: @tobi303 I don't see anything alike - not on my machine, not on ideone, which showed `stdout: asd1012` to me...

Comment: actually I tried casting, but got some error, maybe I just had a typo. To be honest, I dont care so much for that bug. With that cast it isnt much shorter than writing the usual two lines for creating first the stream and then the string, so I think I will use the helper. Anyhow thanks for the quick answer